# Decoder with many output combination

Tags: decoder, dmx

Is there anyone there that has knowledge if such IC exist? i search in the internet for years like on distributors etc but somehow I can't see any (maybe i don't know the right term or keyword for it to pop-up on search engines).

Only 1 decoder i know that has many output combination and that'll be the decoder for 7 segment only. The rest decoders have only 1 output (e.g 3 to 8 decoder, 1 output H/L and 7 output opposite on the former).

i somehow want to have a decoder flexible enough let's say a 2 to 4 decoder where it can have output combination of:

- LLLL
- HLLL
- HHLL
- HHHL
- HHHH
- LHHH
- LLHH
- LLLH
- HLHL
- HLHH
- HHLH
- LHLL
- LLHL

as i said, all decoders i had searched out (even not dmx-based) have the combination output of only this:

- LHHH
- HLHH
- HHLH
- HHHL

or vice versa.

Aside from shift register, what else could do this kind of combination output that is a decoder and what exactly the term used for these kind of decoders.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You provided 13 output combinations using 2 inputs posing only 4 selection permutations? Pretty fancy compression you have. Also, the first bunch of them in sequence looks an awful lot like a twisted (Johnson) ring counter to me.

Comment: i am planning to control +60 SPI devices and since i can only control them 1 at a time (1 SPI controller/Master only on a uC), i want to have +60 slave selects. My uC has 12-15 pins only so i have in mind to achieve this is by decoders/multiplexer, i even resort on i/o expanders but they are same as shift registers but uses SPI so i can't resort to that. Though shift registers would do, i still want to know & use a decoder if such exist.

Comment: @jonk :D thanks, never knew that johnson ring counter, going to check it out.

Comment: The PIC16F57 and PIC16F59 make great i/o expanders. Cheap too. Plus, you can code them so they do whatever you want. But I don't see the problem. If you have to use individual select wires, just use standard decoders and chain them together. Like the 74154. If you want 64 selects, that is four 74154 plus half a 74139. You use up six io pins for selection. If you don't like that, use the PICs I mentioned and send the address serially. Then just two or three io pins.

Comment: @jonk Well, when it comes to your suggestion using decoders, i indeed ended up designing already using 6 pcs 4-to-16 dmx & another 1 pcs 3-to-8 dmx to select which 4-to-16 dmx should work every time i want SPI master to talk to a certain SPI device among the 60. I ended up using 6 pcs because +60 SPI devices are divided into 3, (like 20 SPI devices per board among among those 20 are divided into 2 different sensors, 10 pcs sensorA & 10 pcs sensorB) that's why it ended up redundant & i don't want to mix sensorA & B on same decoder to have uniformity.

Comment: @jonk also, what makes me not to rely on shift register is that due to process time. Isn't that a big difference when i want to control SPI devices real-time? isn't it fast if you will just create like 3-4 input combination from the uC i/o pins towards decoders instead of shifting 10 inputs to have 10 input combination?

Thanks also for the PIC :D i'll check them all.

Comment: @Mheruian You haven't written nearly enough for me to say what's a problem and what is not. I'm just shooting from the hip because you've given too little for more than that. -- No, you can serial out 6 address bits in less than \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$ and if you use a microcontroller with buckets of I/O pins on it (they exist) they can operate the select line in just a few more microseconds. That leaves you able to operate your SPI in very, very short order. Since you are doing them one at a time, I don't think there is a problem here.

Comment: @Mheruian If you go with FPGA (and I've used them, but I'm no expert either), there is a lot to learn. And they are expensive. And boutique, with no two manufacturers providing the same basic cell structures. Floorplanning took me some added time to work through, too. (Stupid automatic floorplanning seemed to waste resources like it's water.) But they certainly can do a lot today. You could just get rid of your MCU entirely and use a free CPU inside the FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

> Aside from shift register, what else could do this kind of combination
>   output that is a decoder and what exactly the term used for these kind
>   of decoders.

If you need a large logic device capable of providing decoded outputs for various combinations of inputs I'd consider an [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) (field programmable gate array).

Comment: :D thanks for the help Andy, i would look into this FPGA, first time hearing this one.

Comment: @Mheruian everyone is using them these days it seems. Steep learning curve so make sure you understand the cell structure and the programmable interconnect limitations but if you are keen on sweeping up glue logic and/or operating at frequencies that glue logic is incapable of then it’s gonna be for you.